# Option generateNextPrev of SlideJS doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've got a problem with SlideJS. I dont want to display the previous/next-Buttons, so i've set the Option generateNextPrev to false. But that doesnt do anything.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Here is the Code:

```
            $("#articlesSlider1").slides({
            generateNextPrev: false,
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            width: 700,
            height: 320,

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first in your HTML markup. And search for code below:

```
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</i></a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</i></a>
```

Delete it, and try again. If you already added that prev/next in your code, **generateNextPrev: false,** won't work. Normally you don't need to add that link in markup, since Slidejs can generate that prev/next links.